# sum of values based on condition

Tags: mysql

Iam new to mysql
I have two tables,

```
CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
  `tid1` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `payer` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `receiver` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `payAmt` decimal(20,2) default '0.00',
  `recAmt` decimal(20,2) default '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tid1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tab1`

```
INSERT INTO `tab1` (`tid1`, `payer`, `receiver`, `payAmt`, `recAmt`) VALUES 
(1, 'aaa', 'bbb', 100.00, -100.00),
(2, 'aaa', 'ccc', 200.00, -200.00),
(3, 'bbb', 'aaa', 150.00, -150.00),
(4, 'ccc', 'aaa', 175.00, -175.00);
```

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tab2`

```
CREATE TABLE `tab2` (
  `tid2` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `payer` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `receiver` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `payAmt` decimal(20,2) default '0.00',
  `recAmt` decimal(20,2) default '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tid2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tab2`

```
INSERT INTO `tab2` (`tid2`, `payer`, `receiver`, `payAmt`, `recAmt`) VALUES 
(1, 'ddd', 'aaa', 223.00, -223.00),
(2, 'aaa', 'bbb', 429.00, -429.00),
(3, 'ccc', 'aaa', 102.00, -102.00);
```

I want the result as shown below

```
name    payAmtTotal recAmtTotal payAmtTotal-recAmtTotal
aaa        729       650          79
bbb        150       529         -379
ccc        277      -277          554
ddd        223        0           223
```

Comment: @PeterM SELECT payer,receiver,SUM(payAmt) AS payAmt,SUM(recAmt) AS recAmt  FROM(
SELECT payer,receiver,payAmt,recAmt FROM `tab1`
UNION ALL
SELECT payer,receiver,payAmt,recAmt FROM `tab2`
)x group by payer,receiver

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why there is more then 1 table with this information, first thing that comes up is trying to turn this into 1 table.

Anyway, not sure if this is the best and cleanest way bu if the tables aren't to large and you have to option of creating temporary tables then here's one way of getting the desired results.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS (SELECT * FROM `tab1`);
INSERT INTO temp1  SELECT * FROM `tab2`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp2 AS (SELECT * FROM `temp1`);
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp3 AS (SELECT * FROM `temp1`);

SELECT 
    `payer` AS `name`,
    (SELECT SUM(payAmt) AS `p` FROM temp2 AS t WHERE t.payer = temp1.payer) AS `payAmtTotal` ,
    (SELECT SUM(payAmt) AS `r` FROM temp3 AS t WHERE t.receiver = temp1.payer) AS `recAmtTotal`
FROM
   temp1
GROUP BY `name`;
```

Basically you create a singe (temporary) table and fill this table with the data from the two existing tables.

Since MySQL won't let you use the same temporary table more then once in a single query you need to create a few more :-) they can be copies of the first one though.

After that the selection query on itself isn't that complicated.